# ValueError: shapes (1,10) and (20,20) not aligned: 10 (dim 1) != 20 (dim 0)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I am new to machine learning and I am getting this error when I try to execute the `.predict()` method on `X_test`. I also don't understand the concept of `reshape`: why do we need to do that?

```py
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('Salary_Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:,-1].values  
y = dataset.iloc[:,1].values 



# Splitting the dataset into the Training set and Test set
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size = 1/3, random_state = 0)



# Fitting simple Linear Regression to the training set
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
regressor= LinearRegression() 
X_train = X_train.reshape(1, -1)
y_train = y_train.reshape(1, -1)
regressor.fit(X_train,y_train)



# Predicting the test set results
X_test= X_test.reshape(1,-1)
y_pred = regressor.predict(X_test)
```

Comment: Can you actually ask a question ? Where do you encounter a problem with your example ?

Answer (score 1):

I have to use **.reshape(-1, 1)** instead of .reshape(1, -1)
since i am considering only one feature from my data set

Answer (score 0):

Reshape is required since the data need to have the same dimensions over the `fit()` and the `predict()` methods. Linear regression assume that:

- The number of columns represent the number of dimension per sample
- The number of rows represent the number of sample

So it is ok to have a different number of rows (you can train a model on 100 samples but just want to predict one sample. However, you cannot train (i.e. `fit`) a model with samples containing `n` dimensions and predict a sample containing a different number of dimensions.